# How can I get more volume to my (bass-)voice?

Tags: voice, bass-voice

I'm a 19 years old male and my (singing!) range is F2-B3, although my I can get down to D2 when I am relaxed.

My friends and I are singing sometimes and then I am mostly the deepest voice.

The weird thing is, that when my friends are singing for instance a C3 or a B2 it sounds very deep that I start to hit a F2 or G2, to sound as deep. But then I realize that I have to go up many notes - which was irritating at first, as my C3 or B2 sounds like a high note compared to the C3 or B2 of the guy next to me... I hope you know what I mean.

The guy next to me has just more volume, so more "in the chest"! When I am singing the same note, it sounds more straining, more "in the throat".

Does anybody of you know some advice how I can improve my volume? Is it about being relaxed?

Comment: I suspect that this is simply a consequence of your lower voice being compared to someone else's, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously your range will differ from others, as will your tone. It really isn't super profitable to compare your sound to theirs.

You are correct about relaxing and opening the throat; often basses try to "dig" for the low notes and this creates tension which is not a good thing. Go as low as you can in a relaxed open tone, regardless of what your friends can or can't do.

Your volume will naturally peter out as you approach the bottom of your range. Hit the notes you can hit and don't strain yourself trying to churn out the ones you can't.

Hope this helps!